# How do I find out where an Opera extension stores its data and settings?

Tags: opera

I am trying to find where an Opera web browser extension stores its data and settings so I can make a backup. In my case, I am trying to find the [Reddit Enhancement Suite](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/reddit-enhancement-suite-2/?display=en) extension's cache and settings location.

In Windows 7, Opera extension files (.OEX) and their data and configuration is stored in this folder `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\widgets\`. (This directory name may vary depending on the Opera 'Program Files' folder name. This could be `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera x64\widgets`, with the 64-bit version of Opera.)

The extension data and configuration are stored in folders with filenames starting in `wuid-` (e.g. `wuid-4e342642-00b0-09e4-08b5-63f200fbf89d`), with one *wuid-...* folder for each extension.

**How do I identify which `wuid-...` folder contains which extension's data and settings?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, latest Opera (new version 23) settings and data is stored in the folder(location) :

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\
```

or another location:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Opera Software\Opera Stable\
```

Comment: This is where I found them, in 2019.

Answer (score 3):

In Opera 12, you can find the *wuid...* folder name of installed Opera extensions by opening *widgets.dat* in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\widgets` folder using a text editor. Use the search function of your text editor to find the extension name, and then see the value of the `<section id>` tag above it, which should contain the *wuid...* folder name.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera GX Stable\Extensions

Answer (score -2):

For older opera versions i.e. 6th, back up your F:\Program Files\Opera\opera6.ini file where all these MIME/extension configurations are stored

For newer versions refer the [link](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1129212)

Comment: [Opera introduced extensions in v11](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Opera_browser#History), so my question does not apply for older versions (i.e. 6th). The [link you provided](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1129212) does not show how to identify where an extension's cache and settings will be located, and which `wuid` folder belongs to which extension. It only shows where extension files (.OEX) are located - a detail already in my question.